# Identificar porta local de servidor tomcat

Tags: java

Eu tenho um script java rodando dentro de uma webapp no tomcat, ela é responsável por enviar arquivos em nuvem, porém eu preciso montar a URL completa do arquivo (ip:porta/nome_da_webapp/static/Relatorios/arquivo.csv), minha dúvida é como eu consigo identificar a porta onde a aplicação que executa o script está rodando. Por exemplo, se a minha aplicação estiver rodando na porta 8080, preciso de um int nesse código que retorne 8080.

Tentei esse código, mas ele retorna 0 na porta

```
public static String getContext() throws UnknownHostException {
        
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String hostname = ip.getHostName();
        String serverName = ip.getHostAddress();
        int port = socket.getLocalPort();
        
        System.out.println("hostname: "+hostname);
        System.out.println("serverName: "+serverName);
        System.out.println("porta: "+port);
        
        return hostname;
    }
```

Comment: Ainda está com o problema, ou, já solucionou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Há** uma pergunta *muito similar* a sua neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929071/get-port-number-host-name-in-a-spring-application-on-tomcat-server) (aqui mesmo no S.O.), dê uma olhada.